# moving from old plain TeX to XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I have a style file I used for a project in pre-Unicode age. Now I want to convert it for use in XeTeX. I used Computer Modern and now would like to use CMU Serif. Pointers on what to do with the following block of code will be much appreciated.

```
%%%%%%%%
\font\BIG=cmr17         %for titlepages
\font\Big=cmr17
%\font\mid=cmr12 scaled\magstep1
\font\big=cmr12
\font\ninesc=cmcsc9     %for headers
\font\sc=cmcsc10
\font\eightsc=cmcsc8
\font\sb=cmbx7
\font\sm=cmr7
\font\smit=cmti7
\font\itbf=cmbxti10
\font\bfxiv=cmbx12 scaled \magstep1
\font\bfxii=cmbx12
\font\sym=cmsy10
\font\symkl=cmsy8
\font\symklviii=cmsy7

\def\eightpoint{\def\rm{\eightrm}%
           \def\acc{\ieaccsm}%
           \def\it{\eightit}%
           \def\sl{\eightsl}%
           \def\bf{\eightbf}%
           \def\pl{\eightpl}%
           \def\sym{\symkl}%
           \def\gr{\eightgr}%
           \def\symkl{\symklviii}%
                \def\dag{{\symkl\char'171}}%
           \def\sc{\eightsc}%
%              \def\itbf{\eightitbf}%
%\baselineskip=9pt%
           \lineskip=0pt%
           \rm}
    \def\it{\fam\itfam\tenit%
     \def\sub##1{\lower.5ex\hbox{{\smit##1}}}%
     \def\sup##1{\raise.8ex\hbox{{\smit##1}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The most important aspect is whether you're using accents in your text.

Comment: Yes, my text contains many accents. I believe the version of CMU Serif I am using has been doctored to accommodated most of the diacritics that I need. (I work on Vedic Sanskrit.)

Comment: If you don't use the “old commands” such as `\'` or `\.`, but always Unicode characters, there should be no problem

Answer (score 5):

I won't convert every of your commands but three typical can be done like this

```
\font\BIG="CMU Serif" at 17pt 
\BIG blablb

\font\sc="CMU Serif:+smcp"
\sc Blabla

\font\itbf="CMU Serif/BI"
\itbf
Blalblab
\bye
```

[image]

You can find some information about the various font settings in xetex-reference.pdf

Comment: Thanks you. This is a great start. I'll try to take it from here.